# Обновление данных при загрузке игры unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Проблема такая: у меня есть скрипт для магазина в unity на C#, улучшение по дефолту стоит 15 монет

При покупке улучшение, стоимость увеличивается в 2 раза, когда игрок выходит из игры и заново заходит, цена сохраняется в массиве с ценами, но отображается как 15 монет, и остается таковой пока игрок не купит это улучшение уже за большую цену (о которой он не знает), после чего цена увеличится, как сделать так, что-бы когда игрок снова заходил, у него отображалась именно цена, которая в массиве

```
 void GetShop(int id)
 {
     switch (id)
     {
         case 0:
             if (LinaMain.LinaScore >= PickLina)
             {
                 LinaMain.LinaScoreSec += 1;
                 LinaMain.LinaScore -= PickLina;
                 PickLina *= 2;
                 arrayCost[id] = PickLina.ToString();
                 list[0].GetComponentsInChildren<Text>()[2].text = ShortScaleString.parseFloat(PickLina,1,1000,true).ToString();
                 SoundPlay.Play();
                 PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("PickLina", PickLina);
                 if (PickLina <= 0)
                 {
                     PickLina = 30;
                 }
             }
```

Сохраняю все через PlayerPrefs, которые загружаются в start

Comment: А где вы загружаете? Покажите код. Из показанного обрезка непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в Start(), после получения значений из PlayerPrefs, обновлять UI магазина.

А так, конечно, хотелось бы побольше информации о проблеме, так не совсем ясно в чем ошибка.